# Removing a String from a String REGEX

Tags: regex

I have an automatically generated string which looks as follows:

```
["January","February",null,"April"]
```

I need to remove any match of ",null" from the string, ie:

```
["January","February",null,"April"] --> ["January","February","April"]
```

How can I find everything except for `",null"`?

I have tried variations of `"^(?!,null).*"` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as stated, you don't need regex:

```
str = str.replace(",null", "");
```

However, to handle the edge cases too:

```
["January","February",null,"April"] --> ["January","February","April"]
["January",null,null,"April"] --> ["January","April"]
[null,"January","February","April"] --> ["January","February","April"]
["January","February","April",null] --> ["January","February","April"]
[null] --> []
```

you *would* be better served with regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\[)null,?|,null", "");
```

The replacement regex caters for `null` the first (and potentially only) position, and any other case.

Comment: Wouldn't that also shave off the trailing quote of the item before it, or the leading quote of the item after it?

Comment: @Joe Edited with tested solution. Interestingly, the null in first position was the only "interesting" case. In every other position, it's just a delete of `,null` that's required.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this one, we can use filter function

```js
var arr = [null, "January","February",null,"April", null];

var arr2 = arr.filter(function(x){return x !== null})

console.log(arr,arr2);
```